# In laravel The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD Plz

Tags: php, laravel, version

I new in Laravel when I update the value then I face this problem. Message by Laravel is

> "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD".

I also use these methods ( `@csrf_field` and `{{ method_field('PUT') }}` ) but result is zero.

**HTML Form**

```
 <form action="{{ $value[0]->id }}" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">

    <h1>This Is Update Form</h1>

    <table border="1" id="customers">

        <tr>

     <td>Name</td>

     <td>
       <input type="text" name='name' value="{{ $value[0]->name }}">
     </td> 
    </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>Email</td>

     <td>
       <input type="text" name='email' value="{{ $value[0]->email }}">
     </td> 

     </tr>

     <tr>

       <td colspan="2">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
       </td>

     </tr>

    </table>
 </form>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function showid($id)
 {
    $data =DB::select('select * from student where id =?',[$id]);
      //DB::table('student')->pluck('id');
    return view('std_edit',['value'=> $data]);
 }

 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {

    //$data = DB::table('student')
    //->where('id', $data['id'])
    //->update(['name'=>$data['name'], 'email'=>$data['email'] ]);
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    DB::update('update student set name = ? email = ? where id = ?',[$name,$email,$id]);
     return redirect()->action('StudInsertController@retrieve');
      echo "Record updated successfully.<br/>";
     //$update = \DB::table('student') ->where('id', $data['id'])->update( [ 'name' => $data['name'],'email' => $data['email'] ]);



 }
```

**Route**

```
 Route::get('edit/{id}','StudInsertController@showid');
 Route::post('post/id','StudInsertController@update');
```

Comment: You are putting the wrong URL in from action please check

Answer (score 2):

Use named routes and give your route a name and also i've fixed your route problem to accept param in url we have to use `{{ param_name}}` which in your case is `{{ id }}`

```
Route::post('post/{id}','StudInsertController@update')->name('update.student');
```

and then in your form

```
<form action="{{ route('update.student', $value[0]->id) }}" method="post">
   @csrf

   /**Your rest of html form*/

</form>
```

if you don't want to use named routes then you can use `url` method of laravel.

```
 <form action="{{ url('post/'.$value[0]->id) }}" method="post"> @csrf

 /**Your rest of html form*/

</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: @kashif if it helped you mark it as accepted answer so that others will also get benefit from this. Thanks

Comment: Bro Salman Zafar thank you very much you solve my problem thnx again

Answer (score 0):

The action in the form is wrong. Try this:

```
    <form action="{{ "/post/" . $value[0]->id }}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing wrong route to your form action. Change your `form action` **from** :

```
<form action="{{ $value[0]->id }}" method="post">
```

**to:**

```
<form action="{{ "/post/" . $value[0]->id  }}" method="post">
```

EDIT:

Just saw you defined your post route wrong as well. Change it to:

```
Route::post('post/{id}','StudInsertController@update');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form action URL should be like

```
<form action="{{ 'post/'.$value[0]->id }}" method="post">
```

And in your route file

```
Route::post('post/{id}','StudInsertController@update');
```

This will resolve your issues